# Finding the $y$ value of an interpolated function given an $x$ value

Tags: equation-solving, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate my dataset, which is a list of points. Thus I have two interpolated functions of my x data and y data:

```
datax={19.668, 18.5235, 17.581, 16.7985, 16.1445, 15.595, 15.1315, 14.7395,
14.4075, 14.1265, 13.8885, 13.6875, 13.518, 13.3765, 13.2585, 13.162,
13.083, 13.0205, 12.9715, 12.935, 12.909, 12.892, 12.8835, 12.8815,
12.885, 12.8935, 12.906, 12.9215, 12.9395, 12.9595, 12.98, 13.001,
13.022, 13.0425, 13.0615, 13.0785, 13.094, 13.1065, 13.1165, 13.1235,
13.1265, 13.126, 13.122, 13.1135, 13.1005, 13.0835, 13.062, 13.0355, 
13.005, 12.97, 12.9305, 12.8865, 12.838, 12.786, 12.7295, 12.6695,
12.606, 12.539, 12.469, 12.396, 12.32, 12.242, 12.1615, 12.079,
11.995, 11.9095, 11.823, 11.7355, 11.647, 11.558, 11.469, 11.38,
11.291, 11.2025, 11.1145, 11.0275, 10.9415, 10.8565, 10.7725, 10.69,
10.609, 10.53, 10.453, 10.3775, 10.304, 10.233, 10.164}


 datay={0.161158, 0.17188, 0.183499, 0.196057, 0.209601, 0.224179, 0.239842,
0.256644, 0.274639, 0.293882, 0.314433, 0.336349, 0.359688, 0.384507, 
0.410862, 0.43881, 0.468401, 0.499684, 0.532704, 0.567499, 0.604103, 
0.642541, 0.682831, 0.724979, 0.768983, 0.814829, 0.862489, 0.911922, 
0.963073, 1.01587, 1.07023, 1.12604, 1.1832, 1.24156, 1.30096, 
1.36126, 1.42226, 1.48377, 1.54559, 1.6075, 1.66927, 1.73069, 
1.79152, 1.85153, 1.91048, 1.96817, 2.02436, 2.07887, 2.13148, 
2.18203, 2.23035, 2.27629, 2.31974, 2.36058, 2.39873, 2.43413, 
2.46673, 2.49651, 2.52347, 2.54761, 2.56897, 2.58759, 2.60354, 
2.61689, 2.62772, 2.63613, 2.64222, 2.64609, 2.64786, 2.64765, 
2.64558, 2.64177, 2.63633, 2.6294, 2.62109, 2.61152, 2.6008, 2.58906, 
2.57639, 2.5629, 2.5487, 2.53389, 2.51855, 2.50278, 2.48667, 2.47028, 
2.45371}

fx=Interpolation[datax]
fy=Interpolation[datay]
```

I can then plot these together using ParametricPlot:

```
ParametricPlot[{fx[x], fy[x]}, Evaluate@{x,Sequence @@ First@Interpolation[datax]["Domain"]}]
```

And it gives me a nice interpolated version of my original data.

My issue is, now I need to find a specific y-value corresponding to x_o=1.4 on this parametric plot, which I've found to be impossible (?).

So what I'm doing is the following:

First, plot each interpolated function separately:

```
 Plot[{fx[x], fy[x]}, Evaluate@{x, 
   Sequence @@ First@Interpolation[datax]["Domain"]}]
```

Which gives me my two interpolated functions:

[image: Interpolated functions]

Next, I Find the X-value of my fy interpolated function:

```
xroot = x /. FindRoot[fy[x] == 1.4, {x, 35}][[1]]
(*36.6362*)
```

And now I need to find the corresponding Y-value of my fx interpolated function.

My issue is, I have no idea how to find a y-value given an x-value! I have tried:

```
FindRoot[InverseFunction[fx[x]] == sol, {x, 3}]
```

But I get the error:

```
"The function value {-36.6362+InverseFunction[17.581]} is not a `list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {x} = {3.`}"`
```

Does anyone know how to find a y-value given x_o for an interpolated data set? or is there an easier way of doing this??

Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: parts of your code don't evaluate, `ParametricPlot[{datax,datay},{x,0,16.5}]`, other parts are undefined `fm`, `fr`

Comment: Sorry! My bad. I just fixed it so it runs :)

Comment: @zack your code still does not run. You should try to copy your code from this question and execute it *in a clean MMA kernel* to make sure that you provided us enough information to run it.

Comment: This is pretty unclear. Are your data points specified by $(x_i,y_i)$ pairs, which you separated into the two sets `datax` and `datay`? If so, then $x_0 = 0.14$ is outside of your domain and I don't think you can calculate the corresponding $y_0$ with the information you have. If, on the other hand, you want to calculate the $x_0$ for which $y=0.14$, then try `InverseFunction[Interpolation@Transpose@{datax, datay}][1.4]`, which returns `13.1814`.

Comment: Looks like you have fx and fy switched.

Comment: Sorry about the messy post guys! I've fixed it so it should definitely work. You were right Marco - I was running it in a "dirty" kernel and had some leftover names that wouldn't work for you. Anyway, Carls' answer below gave the right number!

For some reason, your function (Marco) gave me an answer which was 0.0072 away from the correct answer.. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is how you could use [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction) to find the $x$ value for a given $y$:

```
ify = InverseFunction[fy];
fx[ify[1.4]]
```

> 13.0886

Of course, you have no control over which $y$ value is used.

Or finding the $y$ value for a given $x$:

```
ifx = InverseFunction[fx];
fy[ifx[15]]
```

> 0.245044

Comment: Thank you so much Carl! I've been trying to get this to work all day and your simple solution worked wonders! Your first line gave me the exact answer I need.